# Binding to xaml page's DataContext in Windows Universal App

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm using a content dialog do display instance data when an item in a grid is selected.

In the calling page's view model, when an item is selected the following method is executed.

```
public virtual void ItemSelected(object sender, object parameter)
{
    var arg = parameter as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemClickEventArgs;
    var clickedItem = arg.ClickedItem;
    var item = clickedItem as ItemsModel;

    var dialog = new ItemsDialog();
    dialog.DataContext = item;
    dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

This shows the dialog, and the content is displayed as expected. Now I'm trying to split my xaml into different templates and I'm trying to use a `ContentControl` to display the appropriate template. I've written a `DataTemplateSelector` to help choose the correct template, but now I cannot figure out the data binding for the `ContentControl` (see simplified version below).

```
<ContentDialog.Resources>
    <UI:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"
            Template1="{StaticResource Template1}"
            Template2="{StaticResource Template2}"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2"/>
</ContentDialog.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding}"
        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

When debugging into my `ContentTemplateSelector`, my binding is always `null`. I've tried various forms of the binding syntax with no luck. How do I properly set the `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` to that of the `ContentDialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When debugging into my ContentTemplateSelector, my binding is always
>   null

You need to set data binding for the Content property of ContentControl control, see Remarks in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol):

> The Content property of a ContentControl can be any type of object,
>   such as a string, a UIElement, or a DateTime. By default, when the
>   Content property is set to a UIElement, the UIElement is displayed in
>   the ContentControl. When Content is set to another type of object, a
>   string representation of the object is displayed in the
>   ContentControl.

So the following xaml should work:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Check my completed sample in [Github](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/GridViewMVVMApp1)

[image]

Comment: I've also tried setting `Content="{Binding}"` with no luck. I'll take a look at your sample.

Comment: Debugging through your sample, I noticed the first time through `SelectTemplateCore` that item was null so `base.SelectTemplateCore` is called. This second time item is NOT null. I didn't debug that far into my code. It is working now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind Content also.

```
Content="{Binding}"
```

You have the data source (DataContext) and how the data is displayed (templates) and now you need to specify which of the properties brings that together.

Comment: I've also tried setting `Content="{Binding}"` with no luck.